# Откуда ОС знает текущую загруженность процессора?

Tags: linux, windows, железо, ос

Кто предоставляет ОС информацию о загруженности процессора, и на основании чего она показывает уровень загрузки ЦП?

Comment: Ну, хм, scheduler как бы часть ОС.

Comment: На основании предыстории и текущих очередей обработки задач. Там некоторая эвристика, но в принципе похоже на правду.

Comment: @0andriy, то есть грубо говоря ОС высчитывает это из соотношения времени занятости процессора за какой-то промежуток к времени этого промежутка?

Comment: @VladD, это Вы про планировщик процессов/потоков, да?

Comment: @Qutrix, мгновенное значение неизвестно, поэтому расчитывается дифференциал.

Comment: @0andriy, вот тут не понял - можно подробнее?

Comment: То, что вы написали, есть дифференциал интегральной характеристики.

Comment: @Qutrix: Угу, он самый. Он считает, сколько квантов времени бежал той или иной процесс/поток, и отбирает у них управление, если нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Какой ОС ?
2. Кто показывает ?
3. Почему "процессора", а не "процессоров" ?

Если говорить о Linux и команде top, то три числа, которые она показывает в поле "Загрузка ЦП", на самом деле показывают среднюю длину очереди задач к данному процессору за последние 3, 5 и 15 минут. Т.е. если это число меньше 1, то всё ОК. Если значительно больше - система перегружена. Но это сугубо оценочные характеристики.

Более точные сведения можно получить используя команду vmstat. Но там статистика идёт не по процессорам, а по процессам.

Ещё более подробную информацию даёт команда mpstat.

Общая идея всех этих статистик заключается в том, что аппаратно считаются "тики" генератора  синхронизации и, в зависимости от значения битов слов состояния процессоров (Система/пользователь, работа/прерывание/ожидание ...) результат пишется в разные части блока статистики. Всё это полностью зависит от архитектуры конкретного проца. Ну и, разумеется, от ОС.

Comment: а кто такой "генератор синхронизации"?

Comment: По другому - тактовый генератор. Грубо говоря, это генератор, выходные импульсы которого поступают на ножки Clk всех схем процессора. Ну, когда говорят, что процессор такой-то работает на частоте столько-то GHz, то это и есть - частота генератора синхронизации.

Comment: @Sergey, к сожалению, когда говорят о ГГц, то частоты *генератора синхронизации* составляют порядок 25МГц (первая гармоника).

Comment: Я предлагаю оставить разговор о том, как и где задаются "тики" процессора электронщикам - они в этом разбираются  лучше программистов. Просто в ядре есть понятие "тик" и есть (ядерная) функция для перевода "тиков" в секунды и доли секунды. Для меня этого знания достаточно.